# incorrect Filename when downloading from Play 2.6 application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I am trying learn Play Framework.
In the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaStream), under section **Serving files**, when I try following example,

```
def terms = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(
    content = new java.io.File("README.txt"),
    inline = false)
}
```

the downloaded filename is **utf-8''README.txt**, instead of **README.txt**.

Unable to understand **WHY**?

**Configuration**

- Java (1.8.0_131-b11)
- Scala (2.12.2)
- Play (2.6.0)
- SBT (0.13.15)

Comment: which client are you using to download the file ?

Comment: @Mzf Not sure what you meant by _client_. I tried both firefox and chrome browsers, with **http://localhost:9000/terms**, which gets routed to _action_ method in the question.

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7501).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found defect in file **play.api.mvc.Results.scala**. The spurious characters appearing in the dwonloaded filename (**utf-8''**) are present in `Results.scala`, which should not be there.

Built local copy of framework, and after removing those characters, and now file is downloaded with correct name.

---

#### Update

The defect is **NOT** in *Results.scala*, though changing it did solve my problem. As per updates in raised issue, defect is in `akka-http` module, which is default for play-2.6.

---

#### Update

Issue resolved in **Play 2.6.1**.